# How to depict a Network with Donut shaped vertices with Igraph?

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I would like to depict a network with Ring/Donut Shaped Vertices. I did not find such a shape in Igraph documentation, but I found a pie shaped instead. Like the following code:

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_ring(10) 
values <- lapply(1:10, function(x) sample(1:10,3)) 
if (interactive()) { 
    plot(g, vertex.shape="pie", vertex.pie=values,            
         vertex.pie.color=list(heat.colors(5)), 
         vertex.size=seq(10,30,length=10), vertex.label=NA) 
}
```

Here the resulting image:

[image]

Do you know a way of turning a pie shaped vertex into a ring/donut shaped vertex using Igraph itself? I searched for a "vertex.pie.hole" parameter, but it does not exist. The easiest way I see to do this is to depict "white points" in the centroids of the vertices, but it is clearly not an ideal situation.

I also know it is possible to define our own vertex shape, but I must confess it is been really hard for me to do this for a ring/donut shape.

Thanks a lot for your attention,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to plot donuts directly, but here's a hack to get the same result: We plot the graph once using your code, then we overplot smaller white circles to create the donuts. Setting a seed ensures that the vertices are in the same location each time.

```
  set.seed(2)
  plot(g, vertex.shape="pie", vertex.pie=values,            
       vertex.pie.color=list(heat.colors(5)), 
       vertex.size=seq(10,30,length=10), vertex.label=NA) 

  set.seed(2)
  plot(g, 
       vertex.size=seq(5,15,length=10), vertex.label=NA, 
       vertex.color="white", 
       edge.color=NA,
       add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer! Although it is not an ideal situation I see it is definitely a workaround!